# Sort files in folder based on date and time with Python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to loop through all json files in a directory and append their data to my dictionary. It seems as the appending is random and not sorted by date and time, as the files are sorted. Is there anyway to loop and sort the files based on their filename?

I have tried other solutions such as adding
`'time': datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(file_path))` to `json_files` and then sorting it with `json_files.sort(key=lambda x: x['time'])`. The issue is that it is using last modified, and it doesn't seem reliable at all.

**Example files**

```
data/41/2022-12-06 10:39:16.124069.json
data/41/2022-12-06 16:14:19.285462.json
data/41/2022-12-06 10:30:23.831559.json
```

**My code**

```
dir_path = 'data/41'

for file_name in os.listdir(dir_path):
    json_files = []
    file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, file_name)
    with open(file_path, 'r') as json_file:
        try:
            json_data = json.load(json_file)

            # Add the JSON data and the file modified time to the list
            json_files.append({
                'json': json_data
            })
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: "It seems as the appending is random and not sorted by date and time, as the files are sorted." You are seeing results for **one file**, and the reason they aren't sorted is because the **file contents** aren't sorted. This is a typo - please think carefully about the program logic. How many times do you think `json_files = []` ought to happen - only once, or repeatedly every time another file is read? Therefore, should that be inside the loop, or outside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if I understand you correctly, this little trick will give you the desired behaviour:

```
dir_path = 'data/41'

# notice this `sorted` thing
for file_name in sorted(os.listdir(dir_path)):
    json_files = []
    file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, file_name)
    with open(file_path, 'r') as json_file:
        try:
            json_data = json.load(json_file)

            # Add the JSON data and the file modified time to the list
            json_files.append({
                'json': json_data
            })
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: Use `except json.JSONDecodeError`